# Low CNN accuracy only on local GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

For some reason, All my convolutional neural networks have VERY poor accuracy. regardless of the model compiled. This is in jupyter notebook on a local machine using an RTX 3060 TI GPU with CUDA 11.1.

When the I use Google Colab, all my codes work fine with high accuracy. It should be noted this only applied to convolutional neural networks. neural networks with only densely connected layers work fine.

Some details:

```
Tensor Flow Version: 2.1.0
Keras Version: 2.2.4-tf

Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas 1.2.0
Scikit-Learn 0.24.0
GPU is available
```

This is an example code (binary classifcation 50/50 split):

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-6), #decrease learning rate
             metrics=['accuracy'])
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,target_size=(150, 150),batch_size=20,
class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,target_size=(150, 150),
batch_size=20, class_mode='binary')
history = model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
steps_per_epoch=100,
epochs=30,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=50)
```

results

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-8-f61a1535c537>:6: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
Train for 100 steps, validate for 50 steps
Epoch 1/30
100/100 [==============================] - 1158s 12s/step - loss: 0.7020 - accuracy: 0.4945 - val_loss: 0.8541 - val_accuracy: 0.4980
Epoch 2/30
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 47ms/step - loss: 0.6987 - accuracy: 0.5105 - val_loss: 0.6930 - val_accuracy: 0.5000 2s - loss: 0.6931 - accura - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6931 - accura - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6931  - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6926 - accuracy: 0. - ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6939 - accuracy - ETA: 0s - los
Epoch 3/30
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 47ms/step - loss: 0.7000 - accuracy: 0.4985 - val_loss: 0.8449 - val_accuracy: 0.5000s - loss: 0.6983 - accuracy - ETA: 0s - loss:
Epoch 4/30
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 47ms/step - loss: 0.6967 - accuracy: 0.4975 - val_loss: 0.7162 - val_accuracy: 0.4800
Epoch 5/30
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 47ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.4945 - val_loss: 0.8477 - val_accuracy: 0.49900.6931 - accura - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931 - ac - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6931 - 
Epoch 6/30
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 47ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - accuracy: 0.4895 - val_loss: 0.7846 - val_accuracy: 0.5000: 0.6931 - ac
Epoch 7/30
100/100 [==============================] - 5s 47ms/step - loss: 0.6933 - accuracy: 0.4860 - val_loss: 0.7468 - val_accuracy: 0.5000- ETA: 1s - loss: 0.6 - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.6938
```

Comment: I have tried changing the learning rates/varying model.fit() as well as reinstalling for various versions I'm still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason running this code fixes everything. Could someone please care to explain why? thanks

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use Colab so not sure why it trains well on there, perhaps it uses a different version of tensorflow. In model.fit you set the values for steps_per_epoch and validation_steps. I have found it best to leave these as none. Model.fit will automatically determine the correct values. Also model.fit_generator is being depreciated so use model.fit instead. Your learning rate is rather small I would try something like .001. I ran you code on a data set of images with two classes, the model did train but was slow to converge with lr=1e-6. With the learning rate at .001 it converged much faster getting the same accuracy(about 81%) in 3 epochs that was achieved in 30 epochs with the small learning rate. I am using tensorflow 2.1 and had no problems getting you code to work with the exceptions mentioned above. I think the problem may be that you are using CUDA 11.1. I  believe for tensorflow 2.1 you should be using 10.1. You should have cudatoolkit 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.65 installed

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments. After trying changing the learning rates/varying model.fit() as well as reinstalling for various versions I'm still getting the same problem :(

Comment: Hmm in that case all I can think of is to call a priest and try exorcism!  Seriously though your code runs fine on my machine with tensorflow 2,1, python 3,7 etc using windows.